# Laravel 6 Error: On entering login route app crashes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-6

I'll try to explain my issue as much as possible. I just created a Laravel application. Whenever I'm logged in either as a user or admin (user route is **http://localhost/Folder/** and admin route is **http://localhost/Folder/admin**) and I enter the login view path i.e. **http://localhost/Folder/login**
it takes me to this page: **http://localhost/Folder/home** with error message **Page Not Found**

I have not added any route of /home in my routes. What I want is on entering the login path, the user should stay on the same page if he is logged in. And the same case for admin instead of going to this path. http://localhost/Folder/home.

Here are the routes for user and admin:

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware(['auth','XSS']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function()
{ Route::get('/admin/dashboard','HomeController@home_page')->name('admin.home');
});
```

Here is my **login controller**:

```
    protected function redirectTo(){
  if (Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') {
    //return 'admin.dashboard';
    return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
  }
  else {
    //return 'home';
    return redirect('/');
  }

}
```

And my **AdminMiddleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') //If usertype is admin
{
   return $next($request);
}
else {
  //  return redirect('home');
    return redirect()->route('/');
}
}
```

All I want is that it should remain logged in while entering the login page route. I'll be happy to provide any other details if required. Any suggestions/solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added login routes? I can't see any defined in your code examples

Comment: I don't think login route is required in web.php file.
Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the route in the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware

It will redirect to /home if it finds that you are already logged in and try to access the login page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload redirectTo method on loginController which you have done and update redirectIfAuthenticated to match your logic.

So go-to your loginController and update

```
protected function redirectTo() {your logic like you have done}
```

Also you will need to update redirectIfAuthenticated middleware to match your logic

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated

{

/**

* Handle an incoming request.

*

* @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request

* @param \Closure $next

* @param string|null $guard

* @return mixed

*/

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)

{

if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);

}

return $next($request);

}

}
```

Also if admin/dashboard is always going to be the home route for your auth and admin middleware. Then instead of changing redirectIfAuthenticated.php just change the HOME constant on routeserviceprovider.php in providers and change to

```
Const HOME = 'admin/dashboard';
```

Comment: Sorry this is all from phone... Just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Where to add this code in routeserviceprovider

Comment: We'll update the home route to / in the service provider, but then overload the $redirectTo on loginController as well as the redirectTo() on the loginController.

Comment: Can you explain with which code do we need to replace $redirectTo and redirectTo()

Comment: I maybe wrong but you will want to look at the logic in the trait being used on the logincontroller and you will see the reference to the home constant. Just over load that function. However I'm pretty sure you haven't overloaded the $redirectTo property or if it's not set it defaults to '/home'

Comment: What version of laravel did you install. This will change where you need to do what slightly.

Comment: It's installed in Laravel 6

Comment: Okay so I just followed it to your issue. If you start on the loginController go-to the trait Authenticatedusers then go-to the trait redirectsUsers you will see the function causing you issues.  /**

* Get the post register / login redirect path.

*

* @return string

*/

public function redirectPath()

{

if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {

return $this->redirectTo();

}

return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';

}

Comment: I don't have any route with /home path

Comment: What I just want is when user is logged in and user enter /login, he should remain on same page instead of logging out

Comment: Sorry on my phone. You need to go to your loginController and add a protected $redirectTo = '/';

Comment: I already have a protected redirectTo function, shall I add protected $redirectTo = '/'; also?

Comment: Or you can over load that redirectPath function on your loginController Either way you won't have a redirect to a home route anymore.

Comment: Yes I would give it a shot

Comment: You could also add some dd() or dumps to check your logic

Comment: Or shoot you want it to be admin/dashboard not /

Comment: But if you dump and die in that redirectto function you will know if you are reaching it.

Comment: Your other issue is you are probably hitting the redirectedIfAuthenticated.php and redirect... I will update

Comment: Please update your answer accordingly and remove the unnecessary points

Comment: They are all necessary you have created a middleware that has ripples of changes in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The last method of changing const HOME seems good. But home is not same for both user and admin. For user the home is '/' and for admin it is '/admin/dashboard'

Comment: thanks for your suggestions and time. I sorted out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I just tried something and it worked.
In the **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php** file:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Just changed `return redirect('/home');`

to

`return redirect('/');`

And it worked...

Comment: Thought that is what I said?  Why was it necessary to add your own answer?

Comment: @Snapey I appreciate your answer, but you didn't add any code snippet and I sorted out this issue before your answer. Thanks again

Comment: Same here. I literally to you that.

Comment: Code snippet?  you only had to remove the word 'home'

Comment: @Snapey That's why I just gave an upvote to your answer. I will mark your answer as the accepted one if you want that. Kindly upvote my question if possible.